# Space between widgets inside of centralwidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to have two widgets on top of each other but with the code I use I get a space between the two widgets around the center.

Example Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1GGj.png

Code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setGeometry(0,0,250,250)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)

        button1 = QPushButton('1')
        button2 = QPushButton('2')

        vbox.addWidget(button1)
        vbox.addWidget(button2)

        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
```

How do I align the two widgets on top of each other and to the top of the window?

Comment: `vbox.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)`

Comment: or alternatively use `vbox.addStretch()` after adding the second button.